# JOIN tables by DATE column in MYSQLI'

Tags: mysql, date, hash, time-series, sorting

I have a few tables with time series whose first column corresponds to the date of the data.  I tried to merge them together based on that column, but the query takes toooo long.

Since the series aren't very short, I'm guessing it is trying to search through many entries in order to do the JOINT.  Is there a way to optimize the search?  maybe use a hash function, or let MYSQL know the data is sorted already.

Thank you kindly, below is part of the code on which execution is delayed.

```
SELECT 
    a.PERIOD,
    a.INFLATION,
    b.GROSS_PRODUCT,
    c.EMPLOYMENT,
    d.EXCHANGE_RATE
FROM INFLATION a
JOIN PRODUCT b
  ON FLOOR_DATE(a.PERIOD, 'QUARTER') = b.PERIOD
JOIN EMPLOYMENT c
  ON FLOOR_DATE(a.PERIOD, 'MONTH') = c.PERIOD
JOIN PESO_DOLLAR d
  ON FLOOR_DATE(d.PERIOD, 'MONTH') = d.PERIOD
```

I have created `FLOOR_DATE()` to round down to the nearest QUARTER or MONTH, in order to match the corresponding dates.

Comment: Way too vague. Please be more specific.

Comment: Based on the scant information you have provided, I think you want an index.

Comment: I have isolated the part of the program where it takes too long.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very familiar with index making.  I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Setting PERIOD as PRIMARY KEY when creating the table did the trick.